# multiple conditions in oracle case with one :PAR

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

I have a more complex query, but I will give a simple example. In SSRS same input but need different outputs:

```
select * from myTable where
case
when :PAR1 = 'hour' then myTable.hour = :PAR1
when :PAR1 = 'Mounth' then myTable.Mounth = :PAR1
end
```

How to make it?

I'm try to

```
case length(:PAR1)
when 18 then hour: = PAR1
..
```

always a mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `CASE` expression here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (:PAR1 = 'hour' AND hour = :PAR1) OR
      (:PAR1 = 'Mounth' AND Mounth = :PAR1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code you posted doesn't make sense to me; are you **sure** that `:PAR1` is used *everywhere*? I'd expect something like this instead

```
select *
from mytable
where (:PAR1 = 'hour'   and hour   = :PAR2) 
   or (:PAR1 = 'Mounth' and mounth = :PAR2)
                                    -------
                        maybe not :PAR2, but 
                        certainly not :PAR1
```

Also, when you're dealing with *hours*, what is *mounth*? Shouldn't that be *month*?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question.
The user can enter different data in the same field. Like a year, a month, an hour. And I need to display data on this condition from one table. In the working example, the query is 150 rows, includes five different tables and is a collection of information

Comment: OK, but I'd expect that user enters e.g. 'hour' (a string) into :PAR1 and e.g. 5 (a number) into :PAR2, so query returns rows from that table where HOUR column's value equals 5 (hours). To me, it doesn't make sense that they enter 'hour' and query returns rows where HOUR column's value equals 'hour' (a string). It would probably be easier to understand if you posted sample data that illustrates the problem. But, nonetheless, that (i.e. code Tim and me posted) is the way to properly write that piece of code.

Comment: Thank you.
For your understanding of the issue.
Logistics.
There is an internal route number.
There is an integration route number.
There is also a general one, in which there can be several routes.
All three types of routes are written differently. And it is more convenient for managers of different departments to search for a route by their number.
The example with hours and months is greatly simplified, but it helped to give the answer I needed, maybe the comparison is not very correct.

Comment: You're welcome. OK then, I'm glad you got the answer you were looking for :)